# Problem in implementing a linkedlist in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am learning C++ and trying to implement a singly linkedlist. Basically a linkedlist providing two simple methods, insert and display. Below is the code snippet --

```
class LinkedList {


public:
    int data;
    LinkedList *next;
    LinkedList() {

    }

    LinkedList(int d) {
        data = d;
        

    }

    void insert(int d) {
        LinkedList temp = *this;
        cout << "Calling insert "<< temp.data;
        while (temp.next != NULL) {
            cout << "Inside the while loop"<< temp.data;
            temp = *temp.next;

        }           
        temp.next = new LinkedList(d);      

        


    }

    void display() {
        LinkedList temp = *this;
        cout << temp.data;          
        

        while (&temp != NULL) {             
            cout << temp.data;    
            temp = *temp.next;
            cout << temp.data;              
        } 
        


    } 




};



int main()
{
    LinkedList head(1);
    head.insert(2);
    head.insert(3);
    head.insert(4);
    head.display();

    return 0;
}
```

However, this insert method is not working as expected. Even after calling insert multiple times, it is never going inside the while loop and "Inside the while loop" is never getting printed. Could you guide what is wrong with my insert method?

Comment: `LinkedList temp = *this;` makes a copy and then you modify the copy.

Comment: *However, this insert method is not working as expected* -- You failed to initialize *all* of your member variables in both of your constructors, and that is just one of a multitude of issues.  `int main() { LinkedList x; x.insert(10); }` -- you don't need any further code to see the issues.

Comment: `LinkedList temp = *this;` creates a local copy of `this`. Hence, `temp.next = new LinkedList(d);` appends the new node to the local copy and is lost as soon as you leave `insert()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to improve more than one thing to keep the code running.

1. Initialize the value of next in constructor. Otherwise you cannot be sure that when `LinkedList` is created next is set to `NULL`

   ```
   LinkedList(int d) : data(d), next(NULL) {}
   ```
2. Use `LinkedList*` instead of `LinkedList` as a `temp` type. Otherwise you won't be modifying the List nodes but local copy of first node. Please note that:

   - `LinkedList temp = *this;` will have to be replaced to `LinkedList* temp = this;`
   - all occurrences of `temp.next` will have to be replaced to `temp->next`
   - all occurrences of `temp.data` will have to be replace to `temp->data`
   - the while condition in `display` function will have to replaced: `&temp != NULL` -> `temp != NULL`
3. The third line in a while loop in `display` function has to be removed as `temp` may point to `NULL`.

The minor thing is that you did not break lines in your output. Please make sure to add `<< endl` in places where you want the line to break.

The big problem is that you still have to implement destructor for the `LinkedList` to release the allocated resources. According to [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), with a destructor you should also define copy constructor and assignment operator.

The other approach would be to use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` to store the address of next node.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
public:
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<LinkedList> next;

    LinkedList(int d) : data(d) {}

    void insert(int d) {
        LinkedList* temp = this;
        cout << "Calling insert "<< d << std::endl;
        while (temp->next) {
            cout << "Inside the while loop: "<< temp->data << std::endl;
            temp = temp->next.get();

        }           
        temp->next = std::make_unique<LinkedList>(d);      
    }

    void display() {
        LinkedList* temp = this;
        
        while (temp != NULL) {             
            cout << temp->data << std::endl;
            temp = temp->next.get();
        } 
    } 
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList head(1);
    head.insert(2);
    head.insert(3);
    head.insert(4);
    head.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++11 and newer, `nullptr` should be used instead of `NULL`.